# Unknown CPU detected, Bios Update is Required to Unleash it's Full Power

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios

I have a [Asus P5K SE](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=P5K%20SE/EPU&os=25) motherboard and I recently changed the CPU from a Core 2 Quad  to a Core 2 Duo. After the change a message displayed at the very beginning of the boot:

`Unknown CPU detected, Bios update is required to unleash it's full power. The system will shutdown after 25 seconds`.

I believe this indicated that I must perform a BIOS update. The problem is that I cannot boot. Not into windows, nor to CDROM or anything else. It is not even letting me to enter the BIOS setup.

How do I flash the BIOS without being able boot from anything?

**Thread UPDATE:** I was able to flash the latest BIOSs without changing the CPU using the integrated ASUS flash tool; after flashing the BIOS successfully and rebooting I got rid from the CPU message; instead I got [this message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCRCj.png) I removed all the USB devices, and the front USB wires, and placed the motherboard on a non metal surface but still have this USB message, any ideas?

Comment: Unleash the Core 2 Quad back into the motherboard, unleash the BIOS update, unleash the Core 2 Duo.

Comment: Have you tried entering the BOIS since flashing the new version? Are you sure the version you flashed was for your make /model of motherboard? Sounds like it may not have flashed properly

Comment: no i cant enter the BIOS after flashing , yes it was for that model and from asus site , i had watched a youtube tut and the flash tool graved me o error messages

Answer (score 1):

Answering this since it is an unswered question since  may 2015 and hence will pop to the front page now and them.

- Either revert to the old CPU and update from a fully working system,
- or use the integrated ASUS flash tool

Comment: He already successfully updated, though. ;)

Comment: True. But it will get popping up and up until it receives an accepted answer. (andif the OP posts his or her answer and accept it then I will be glad).